# Find empty cells of a DataTable except in certain column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm working on a module to upload and validate an Excel file with the ExcelDataReader plugin.
The excel consists on 5 columns per row. I had converted the uploaded file in a DataTable, and now I need to validate there aren't empty or null cells except for the cells of the last column.

I have a snippet to find the nulls with linq, but it works for every column.

```
DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
DataTable excelTable = result.Tables[0];

var rowList = excelTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
var emptyCells = rowList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                         .Where(x => x.value.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value))
                         .Select(x => x.index).ToList();

if(emptyCells.Any())
{
    emptyCells.ForEach(x => {
           data.Errors.Add(new ExcelError { Row = x, Details = "This row has empty cells." });
    });
}
```

How can I exclude the last or an especific column of the DataTable? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `.Where` on the array of values to ignore a particular index:

```
.Where(x => x.value
    .Where((y, idx) => idx != 3)
    .Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value)
)
```